# Factory bonus when some supply piles are exhausted

Tags: puerto-rico

In a recent game of Puerto Rico, I had a Factory with a colonist on it, and I had manned plantations and production buildings to produce four different kinds of goods. However, when the Craftsman was taken, by the time it was my turn to take my production all but one of the supply piles was exhausted, and I was only able to take one barrel.

In this case, do I still get the +3 doubloon bonus from the Factory since I *could* produce four types of goods, or do I not get any bonus since I only *did* take one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No bonus is received.**

You only get credit for what you produce. See [the rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_4_gameRules.pdf), page 10.  The answer is clear within the Example for the factory.

Comment: That is pretty darn clear. The person holding the rulebook in our game didn't notice the example for some reason, and so we ruled that I got the bonus anyway.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ That happens, writing rules that are clear is hard and even if a designer succeeds some folks will have blind spots about certain things!